# php Compare datetime with hours variation

Tags: php, datetime

I have two DateTime, one in database in the same php DateTime format: Y-m-d H:i:s. One is stored in a database and one is retreived.

Unfortunately the second one cannont be compared exactly becazuse there is a certain time (hours) difference. It should be exactly the same time but the difference makes it hard to do a DateTime comparison knowing that comparition must be precise closer to now because of the publish/update date is a matter of a short time (hours, minutes, seconds).

Example: database: 1999-09-06 07:00:00, retrieved: 1999-09-06 09:00:00

I stored the datetime from the distant website a while ago. It worked a few months ago but when I tried to do the same thing today, it failed.

Comment: Please read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html - and look for *time zone*.

Comment: it's not related to database problem because I put and retrieve directly. It would be the same a from a text file.

Comment: I didn't say it's a problem in the database, I just want to find out where the actual problem lies and just wanted to make you aware how Mysql handles the persistence of date and time values. Can you say which Timezone the values have: 1.) In the database, 2.) In the database connection, 3.) Which timezone is the Database server running in, 4.) Which timezone is the Webserver where you execute PHP running in, 5.) Which default timezone you've setup in php.ini, 6.) Which default timezone you've set in your PHP script and 7.) Which timezone you have when you compare. (phew a lot!)

Comment: Also please post some code how you retrieve the datetime value from the database and perhaps a screenshot that demonstrates how you check the value in the databse (e.g. if you're using commandline mysql client or phpmyadmin) (perhaps easier to than what I ask for in my previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the webserver has a different timezone as your local time. You can set the TimeZone for the DateTime Class manually. http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.settimezone.php

Answer (score -1):

If the time difference is always the same, you can simple change one value before comparing it. In PHP you can do that quite easily with the [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) by subtracting 2 hours. The same can be done in MySQL (or any other DB system) by using `SELECT date_column + INTERVAL 2 HOUR`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add